# .NET - Copy from Unmanaged Array to Unmanaged Array

Tags: .net, arrays, copy, unmanaged

I've been looking through the Marshal class, but I can't seem to find a method that allows me to copy from an unmanaged array (IntPtr) to another unmanaged array (IntPtr).

Is this possible using .NET?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also DllImport RtlMoveMemory to get the job done:

```
[DllImport("Kernel32.dll", EntryPoint="RtlMoveMemory", SetLastError=false)]
static extern void MoveMemory(IntPtr dest, IntPtr src, int size);
```

This will also require FullTrust, however, but as you are working with unmanaged code, I'd expect you already have it.

Answer (score -1):

You can revert to using [unsafe code in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288474(VS.71).aspx), if that is an option (typically requires FullTrust permission, which may not be available in all cases).