# copy raw pixel data in c#

Tags: c#, copy, unmanaged

i am trying to copy the pixels of a Bitmap into a DirectX texture. its simple to get the IntPtr's from both, but how do i copy the pixel data efficiently?

```
   var data = FBitmap.LockBits(..)
   var rect = texture.LockRectangle(0, LockFlags.None);

   IntPtr from = data.Scan0;
   IntPtr to = rect.Data.DataPointer;

   //copy data  

   texture.UnlockRectangle(0);
   FBitmap.UnlockBits(data);
```

i tried to use Marshal.Copy but it need the pixels as an array and i would like to avoid another copy of course.

Comment: If you are just trying to assign the image bytes to the address space of the texture, do you need a Bitmap? Can you just read the image from where ever as binary data and then copy that?

Comment: i need to copy the data because there is a SVG renderer which renders its pixels into the bitmap. then the texture is drawn in a 3d environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Windows API [CopyMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366535%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - Alias "RtlMoveMemory". Much faster than all of that LockBits stuff...

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/urlmon/CopyMemory.html

Comment: yes, thats a good idea! i found this code snipped: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3208101/net-copy-from-unmanaged-array-to-unmanaged-array

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about the kind of bleeding edge efficiency where every CPU cycle counts, you're better off just using the data pointer directly with `unsafe` code.

There's no real fast way to map a flat array over an actual managed object like `Array`, you'd have to copy the pixel data byte by byte pretty much.

Comment: +1 - Fastest is unsafe code.  I've tested this multiple times, especially if you want to avoid copies.

Comment: you mean an umanaged for loop over all pixels is faster then a memory move or so?

Comment: Not copying at all is the best copying optimization, yes.

Comment: sure.. but i need a copy, so the SVG renderer can draw new pixels into the bitmap while the texture is displayed.

Comment: I have no idea what you're doing or why, so it's up to you. I do however question your weird mind set of using managed objects as temporary holders for transient texture data that you only really want to push to the graphics card.

Comment: well, i am using a SVG render engine which draws vector graphics into a Bitmap, means what i get out of it is a bitmap. from this bitmap i want to create a texture for further use in a 3d environment. i don't see whats wired about that?